# How would I check if values returned from an SQL/PHP query are empty?

Tags: php, mysql

How would I check to see if the values returned from an sql query are empty? I tried using if(empty($var)), but that didnt work either. heres my code

PHP Code:

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) 
        { 
            if(count($row) == 0) 
            { 
                .... 
            } 
       }
```

How would i check to see if $row is empty?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "empty"?

Comment: Note the mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. Instead, new code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as prepared statements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the right way to do this, you can check if the results are empty by finding number of row in returned results. There is a function in sql to do this `mysql_num_rows`. Here is the method to use it:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Result) == 0) { 
   //results are empty, do something here 
} else { 
   while($admin_row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) { 
      //processing when you have some data 
}
```

Comment: Note you should use === instead of ==.

Comment: For those finding this years later, mysql_num_rows has been replaced by mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Result) == 0) { 
    //error here
} else   {
    //loop here
}
```

Gives you a place for an error and a place to work with the results if they are **not** empty.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [mysql_num_rows()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_num_rows).

```
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($Result);
if ( 0===$cnt ) {
    echo 'no records';
}
else {
    while( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_array($Result)) ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this function returns the number of records that have been transferred from the MySQL server to the client so far. That's not necessarily the total record count. As long as you're using [mysql_query()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_query) that's alright. But if you have e.g. large result sets you might want to use [mysql_unbuffered_query()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_unbuffered_query), and then you can't rely on mysql_num_rows() (for your purpose), because no records have been transferred before you call mysql_fetch_xyz().

But instead you can use something like

```
$cnt = 0;
while( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_array($Result)) ) {
    $cnt += 1;
    // ...
}
if ( 0===$cnt ) {
    echo 'no records';
}
```

Now you have an extra variable as a counter. You might want to avoid that and instead use something like

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($Result);
if ( !$row ) {
    echo 'no records';
}
else {
    do {
        // ...
    } while( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_array($Result)) ) ;
}
```

With that approach you don't have an extra variable but some code duplication (the $x=fetch... line).
... make your choice ;-)